# Trigger PropertyChanged when sub member property changes

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

I have a WPF control that is supposed to be simple to (re)use. For that I have a custom type containing all the settings the control is supposed to represent and bind it over a DependencyProperty.

However, whenever I change one of the members in the control, the parent control gets the changes in the member (when evaluated through other means), but the PropertyChanged-Callback never gets triggered in the parent control.

```
public class Setting
{
    public int Prop {get;set;}
    //Other Properties, Constructor & Copy Constructor, etc.
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Setting other)) return false;
        return Prop == other.Prop;
    }
}

public class SettingControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SettingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
                (nameof(Settings), typeof(Setting), typeof(SettingControl),
                    new PropertyMetadata(default(Setting), OnValuePropertyChanged));

    public Setting Settings
        {
            get => (Setting)GetValue(SettingProperty);
            set
            {
                SetValue(SettingProperty, value);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Settings));
            }
        }

    public int Prop
        {
            get => ((Setting)GetValue(SettingProperty))?.Prop ?? 0;
            set
            {
                //Does not work:
                var temp = (Setting)GetValue(SettingProperty);
                temp.Prop = value;
                Settings = temp;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Prop));

                //Does not work:
                Settings.Prop = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Prop));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Settings));

                //**Does work**, and triggers the OnSettingChanged in the parent control, 
                //but is simply not great memory usage
                Settings = new Setting(Settings){ Prop = value };
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Prop));
            }
        }
}

//Relevant snippet from parent Control ViewModel:
public static readonly DependencyProperty SettingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Settings), typeof(Setting), typeof(ControlViewModel),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(Setting), (d, e) => ((ControlViewModel)d).OnSettingChanged()));
//OnSettingChanged() is never called

public Setting Settings
    {
        get => (Setting)GetValue(SettingProperty);
        set //Set is never called when the member properties are changed
        {
            SetValue(SettingProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Settings));
        }
    }

//Relevant snippet from parent xaml:
<local:SettingControl Width="300"
                      Settings="{Binding Path=Settings, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
// UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged doesn't help here either
```

An obvious solution of course would be to either wrap the `Setting` class into a `SettingViewModel`, or implement it as a ViewModel itself (small testing didn't show results anyway). This however would make the usage of the control a lot harder, and to some degree break MVVM (more than this already). There are also some XML things in the `Setting` class for serialization that I don't want to mess with.

One thing I noticed is that if the `Equals` function in `Setting` is coded to always return `true` the two ways of setting the member property that normally don't work, suddenly work and trigger the desired behavior.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: UserControl shouln't implement INotifyPropertyChanged. All notifications happen via built-in Dependency Property mechanism

Comment: and I disagree that UserControl with a specialized ViewModel is simple to (re)use. A set of Dependency Properties can be configured via Style - and applied *to all* UserControl instances, they don't need VM for that

Comment: To add to @ASh answer i also think that your setter/getter custom code will never be called as it will be stripped when compiled. You should use property change callbacks to add any other logic.

Comment: Those Dependency Property mechanism fail me in this case. They only work if the property itself changes, but completely ignores changed in the sub properties.
@NullReference that the callback never gets call is the issue here. Neither the one in the control, nor the parent. Propagating the change through custom callbacks is also not the idea of WPF.

Comment: @GregorA.Lamche, yes, after introducing a Settings view model properties become sub-properties, and DP notification does't work for them. Unnecessary complication.

Comment: @ASh, just so I understand you correctly, your solution would be to split up the Settings class and bind each property individually? That would be hundreds of lines of code for each control usage.

Comment: @GregorA.Lamche, I probably wouldn't make a UserControl at all and would build a reausable DataTemplate from existing controls instead: No Control -> No ViewModel -> No Problem. food for thought: how are you going to create triggers (e.g. on `int Prop`) when using a control view model?

Comment: @ASh that would for push a lot of logic into the View (XAML) and double the required code that needs to maintained, and usability also reduce usability. Just because xaml can do logic doesn't mean it should.